# Destructed props sent to child component returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I'm a bit lost here.  I've done this a bunch of time and have never had this issue before.  I'm passing a boolean state to a modal component. I followed the code from the parent and it is set properly but as soon as it gets to the modal it returns as undefined.

Here is the parent:

```
import React, { useEffect, Fragment, useState } from 'react'
import './styles.css'
import LandingPageModal from './LandingPageModal'
import { testImages } from './testData'

const LandingPage = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([])
  const [renderImages, setRenderImages] = useState(false)
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setImages(testImages)
    setShowModal(true)
    setIsLoaded(true)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (images && images.length > 0) {
      setRenderImages(true)
    }
  }, [images])

  const FeaturedUsers = () => {
  return (
    renderImages ?
    <Fragment>
        <div className='grid'>
          {images.map((image) => (
            <img src={`/images/${image.src}`} alt={image.caption} />
          ))}
        </div>
    </Fragment> : ''
  )
  }

  return(
    isLoaded ?
      <Fragment>
        <FeaturedUsers />
        <LandingPageModal show={showModal} />
      </Fragment> : ''
  )
}

export default LandingPage
```

and here is the modal:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ReactModal from 'react-modal'
import './styles.css'

const LandingPageModal = ({ showModal }) => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(showModal)
  console.log('Is Show: ' + showModal)

  return (
    <ReactModal
      isOpen={isModalOpen}
    >
      <div className='main-wrapper'>
        <div className='text'>
          <p>
            <strong>Welcome</strong>
            <br />
            <br />
            Please sign in or sign up
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ReactModal>
  )
}

export default LandingPageModal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `LandingPage` component, you accidentally renamed `showModal` to `show`.

Comment: .....So I did.  Thank you.  Fresh eyes and all that.